# How to add section header to custom list view in android?

Tags: android

```
package com.VRG;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Practice extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private Integer prac_sounds[] = { R.raw.cow, R.raw.camel, R.raw.dog,
            R.raw.donkey, R.raw.elephant, R.raw.horse, R.raw.lion, R.raw.rhino,
            R.raw.sheep, R.raw.wolf, R.raw.crow, R.raw.dove, R.raw.duck,
            R.raw.eagle, R.raw.owl, R.raw.parrot, R.raw.rooster, R.raw.cuckoo,
            R.raw.peocock, R.raw.sparrow };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    // I use HashMap arraList which takes objects

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myimages;

    private static final String IMAGEKEY = "imagename";
    private static final String PRICEKEY = "bookprice";

    private static final String IMGKEY = "Images from Drawable";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {

                Log.i("111111111111111111", "" + mp);
                // if ()

                if (mp != null) {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                    }
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(Practice.this, prac_sounds[pos]);
                mp.seekTo(0);
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpalmost) {
                        try {
                            mp.prepare();
                            Log.i("prepare", "during preparing");
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mp.reset();
                        Log.i("reset", "during resetting");
                        // mp = null;

                    }
                });
            }

        });

        myimages = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        HashMap<String, Object> hm;

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "cow");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.cow);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "camel");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.camel);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "dog");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.dog);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "donkey");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.donkey);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "elephant");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.elephant);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "horse");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.horse);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "lion");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.lion);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "rhino");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.rhinos);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "sheep");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.sheep);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "wolf");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.wolf);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "crow");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.crow);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "dove");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.dove);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "duck");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.duck);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "eagle");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.eagle);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "owl");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.owl);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "parrot");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.parrot);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "rooster");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.rooster);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "cuckoo");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.cuckoo);
        myimages.add(hm);


        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "peocock");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.peocock);
        myimages.add(hm);

        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(IMAGEKEY, "sparrow");
        hm.put(IMGKEY, R.drawable.sparrow);
        myimages.add(hm);


        listView.setAdapter(new myListAdapter(myimages, this));

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        // listView.setStackFromBottom(false);

    }

    private class myListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> IMAGES;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public myListAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> images,
                Context context) {

            IMAGES = images;

            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return IMAGES.size();

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return IMAGES.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
                // views

                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.v = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

                holder.v1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

                // holder.rating =
                // (RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView

                // and the ImageView.

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

            // Bind the data with the holder.

            holder.v.setText((String) IMAGES.get(position).get(IMAGEKEY));

            holder.v1.setText((String) IMAGES.get(position).get(PRICEKEY));

            holder.icon.setImageResource((Integer) IMAGES.get(position).get(
                    IMGKEY));

            return convertView;

        }

        class ViewHolder {

            TextView v;

            TextView v1;

            ImageView icon;

        }

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.v("44444", "onBackPressed Called");
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }

        }
        finish();

    }

    public void onKeyDown() {
        onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

Here is my list.xml:

```
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/list"/>
```

Here is my listview.xml:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"

android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="265dip"

    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text1"

        android:textSize="25dip" android:text="This is text1" />
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/speak" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:id="@+id/text2"

        android:text="This is text2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView android:layout_width="55dip"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/img" />
```

Actually I am using one custom list view. In that I have animals, birds and some random images respectively. Now I need to give title to the categories of images. i.e i need to seperate the images according to the category by giving title in the list. Please do me a need ful. Here is my java coding:

Comment: you want to add title to all listview as header..or for each set of particualr rows you want to add title?

Comment: exactly for the second one...! i.e i need to set title for set of rows.. plz do me a needful

Comment: use this tutorial http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

Comment: I am not able to ask questions.. Any one plz help me.....!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) is a complete example of using `Section Header` with a nice explanation as well. You can also download the source code and checkout how it works.

**UPDATE**

You can also see my [blog post](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/07/section-adapter.html)

Comment: I just wanna add one title to particular category...! Plz do me a needful..!

Comment: I guess you want header and some contents below it.... in that way right? For that this is useful. But if you want on 1 header at the top you can use ListView's addHeader.

Comment: Right. But, actually, I am having some list of animal images and birds images. I just wanna give title, to each category.. Simply to seperate animal images and birds images in the list...!

Comment: In that case the above example should work, what problem you are facing.

Comment: Actually I am new to android. So couldn't understand that coding. Can you do one thing..?

Comment: I will give you the coding? can you implement title to my list view categories?

Comment: What is +1 for the nice example?

Comment: Sorry for that, it would be better that you implement it yourself so that you can get the exact idea how it works but if you try and get error then we can try something from what you tried.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SimpleSectionAdapter](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter) that I've written. It works with any of your existing adapters. This should also be the simplest implementation you've come across so far.

Comment: I also have an example for a custom adapter. You can check that out from http://goo.gl/RSkfy

Answer (score 1):

Just found some links that has given the example of listview as you want here,

**[Another Example](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)**

**[Third Project](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/)**

**[THIS IS SAME FOR YOU](http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server)**

Comment: Thanks a lot...! but Still now I am not satisfied.. becos the program mentioned are not working.. But anyhow thanq again...

Comment: not working? what happend? Advice:Change your question title to Section Headers or something like that

Comment: use this tutorial http://umakantpatil.com/posts/android-listview-with-separate-headers-and-images-loading-from-remote-server

Comment: Than q so much...! but i have uploaded another question. if possible plz answer it...

Comment: which question? and it's like none of these 2 answers(mine and @LalitPoptani 's) are useful to your question..? or you forgot to accept/upvote?

Comment: Working in android emulator, but not working in android phone?